# Algorithm for solutions to quadratic forms over number fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

Are there any know (preferably implemented) algorithms to find solutions to quadratic forms over number fields (or global fields)?

I am especially interested in the quaternary case. There exist some algorithms for ternary quadratic forms, some of which are implemented in Magma.

The only algorithm for quaternary forms over the rationals I know of is described in
[Algorithms for solving rational quadratics](http://www.sfb013.uni-linz.ac.at/reports/2004/pdf-files/rep_04-32_pilnikova.pdf) (Schicho, Pílniková). It works by dividing the equation up into two appropriate ternary forms. However I see no easy way to make it work over number fields.